# Plotting a function rescaled by a parameter along x axis

Tags: plotting, symbolic, scaling

I would like to know, how to plot a graph, for example of this function:

$f(t)=-\frac{4 \sin \left(\frac{\gamma  t}{2}\right)}{\gamma ^2 t}-\frac{4 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\gamma  t}{4}\right)}{\gamma }-\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\gamma  t}{2}\right)}{\gamma }+\frac{\pi  t}{2}$ where $t$ is a variable and $\gamma$ is some constant parameter. Is there a possibility to plot it with x axis being in units of notjust $t$, but in units of $\gamma t$?

I was thinking it could be done something like this, but it does not work:

```
Plot[f(t), {\[Gamma]*t, 0, 40}]
```

Comment: Would `ParametricPlot[{\[Gamma]*t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 40}]` do what you want?

Comment: It kinda seems to work, but for \Gamma values less than 1 it gives seemingly correct, but really weird scaled plot. Thanks! Seems, that @Vitaliy Kaurov answer works as well!

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Thanks for accepting the answer. You should give it an upvote too if you fin dit useful :-) please see the [intro for newcomers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your function:

```
f[g_,t_]:=-4Sin[g t/2]/g^2/t-4Sin[g t/4]^2/g-2Cos[g t/2]/g+Pi t/2
```

With transformed variable $z=g*t$ you get a new function:

```
h[g_,z_]=f[g,t]/.t->z/g
```

$$\frac{\pi  z}{2 g}-\frac{4 \sin ^2\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)}{g}-\frac{4 \sin
   \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{g z}-\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{g}$$

which you plot (with, for example, $g=1$) as

```
Plot[h[1, z], {z, 0, 10}]
```